# Wait until internet connection is back python (multithreading API calls)

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a python application which uses multithreading to do several API calls. I need the threads to do the API calls inside a try/except statement, and when I run my program without an internet connection, it falls to the except (URLError) clause. The problems is that I want the threads to wait until the connection to the internet is active again.

If I create 10 threads, I got 10 error messages. How can I make the other threads wait until the internet connection is active again?

Here is the function each thread executes:

```py
def function_thread():
    for i in range (3):   #I try to do the API call 3 times
        try:
            #Here is where I do the API call
        except urllib.error.URLError: #Error: Name or service not known
            print('Revise su conexion a internet')
            self.isConnected = False
            break   #This break statement will lead to the if condition below
        else:
            break   #This break will stop the cycle cause the API call was successful
    else:
        #Here is where I need to deal with user DISCONNECTED

    if not self.isConnected:
        #Here I do the same as the else statement above
```

Im looking for a solution that doesn't leads to CPU hogging. I have been reading some answers from stackoverflow but all of them recommends to use a while loop and it causes my CPU to hog.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I do suggest using a while loop, and to remove the CPU hogging, you could use `time.sleep` to reduce it. If you make it was `2`-`5` seconds, it could greatly reduce the CPU hogging. Usage (pseudocodeish python):

```
import time
while True:
    try:
        # internet connection stuff
        break
    except NoInternet:
        time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: I have tried your solution but it doesn't work. If I create more than 20 threads, it causes CPU hogging.

Comment: @HenryPeregrino -- Then make the threads run at different times, or increase the time.

Comment: The problem with using sleep is that time.sleep is a method based on an specific number of seconds, I am looking for a method based on an event (in this case the event is a flag that tells when the user is connected or disconnected).